# How to extend textarea across 2 rows using CSS grid?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am trying to make the description move down into the 2nd row to align with my other items.

Any help is appreciated

Tried using Grid areas to solve the problem. Then tried to be more specific when identifying the

/ Attempt to expand the textarea across the 2nd and 3rd row

```
section .top-container{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
  "product-details                  product-details                  product-details"
  "product-name                     quantity                         description"
  "price-upc-condition-dimensions   price-upc-condition-dimensions   description";

.description textarea{
  grid-area:description;
}
```

HTML:

```
<section>
  <div class="top-container">
    <div class="product-details">
      <h1>Product Details</h1>
      <hr>
    </div>

    <div class="name-quantity-description">
      <div id="product-name">
        <label>Product Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="product-name-input" placeholder="Enter Product Name">
      </div>
      <div id="quantity">
        <label>Quantity:</label>
        <input type="number" name="quantity-input" placeholder="Enter Quantity">
    </div>
    <div id="description">
      <label>Description: <label>
      <br>
      <textarea name="textarea" rows="10" cols="80"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="price-upc-condition-dimensions">
    <div id="price buttonclass">
      <label>Price: </label>
      <input type="price" placeholder="Enter price">
  </div>
  <div id="upc">
    <label>UPC/EAN: </label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter UPC/EAN"
  </div>
```

What I'm trying to achieve:
[image]

Comment: You are missing a closing curly brace (`}`) `°}° ^{^`

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve] in order to let us help you

Comment: Voting to Close as this question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced **or a simple typographical error**. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.